# With PHP how to force download of file with randon file name and type

Tags: php, download, dialog

I have seen a few answered questions here to force the download of a file but none where the file name and type is not known or can vary.
Also the download is only to be forced when clicking on a link to the file (not on page load/refresh which is what happens during my failed attempts).

I have a folder on the web server that can contain a few different file types with randon file names.
The file types allowed are:
doc, docx, pdf, jpg, jpeg, png and gif (but more will be added later).

The file name is determined by the user who uploads the file using a different php file.

Only the doc and docx are downloaded by the users browsers.

Others are displayed in the browser.

I have tried to get users to right-click the file to download it but this is falling on deaf ears.

The code to display the files is simple enough.

```
<?php

    $dir = opendir('uploads/');

    echo '<ul>';
    while ($read = readdir($dir))
    {
        if ($read!='.' && $read!='..')
        {       

            echo '<li><a href="uploads/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></li>';

        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    closedir($dir);     

?>
```

What I would like is either to force a download dialog to start when they click on the link or a separate download button to the right of the link.

Is this easily possible using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost create a download handler file which will be accepting parameters.

I'll call it download.php

#### download.php

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);  // prevents script termination
set_time_limit(0); // prevent time out

$file =  isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : ''; //get filename

if ($file) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($_GET['file']);
    $file_name = $path_info['basename'];
    $dir = "uploads";  //directory
    
    $path_to_file = $dir.'/'.$file_name; //full path

    if(!file_exists($path_to_file)) {  // check if file exist or terminate request

       exit('the file does not exist');
    }
    
    if(!is_readable($path_to_file)) { //check if file is readable from the directory
     
      exit("security issues. can't read file from folder");

     }
 
// set download headers for file

     $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
     header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $path_to_file));
  
     $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING);
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $path_to_file)); 

     header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path_to_file) . '"'); 

    readfile($path_to_file); // force download file with readfile()
} 

else {

exit('download paramater missing');
}
?>
```

#### Usage

```
<a href="download.php?file=randomfilename.pdf">My pdf </a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks very much. All seems to be working really well. Modifed the usage (to fit my case), to: echo '<li><a href="download.php?file=uploads/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></li>';

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="downloader.php?file=filename.extension">filename</a>
```

Then in the **downloader.php** file

```
<?php

    ignore_user_abort(true);  // prevents script termination
    set_time_limit(0); // prevent time out

    $file =  isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : ''; //get filename

    if ($file) {
        $path_info = pathinfo($_GET['file']);
        $file_name = $path_info['basename'];
        $dir = "uploads";  //directory

        $path_to_file = $dir.'/'.$file_name; //full path

        if(!file_exists($path_to_file)) {  // check if file exist or terminate request

           exit('the file does not exist');
        }

        if(!is_readable($path_to_file)) { //check if file is readable from the directory

          exit("security issues. can't read file from folder");

         }

    // set download headers for file

         $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
         header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $path_to_file));

         $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING);
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $path_to_file)); 

         `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' .` basename($path_to_file) . '"'); 

        readfile($path_to_file); // force download file with readfile()

    } else {

        exit('download paramater missing');
    }

?>
```